# Layered bar chart based on columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with 4 columns and 6 rows. For example:

```
        Healthy    state_A   state_B  state_C
0:      Yes        0         1        1
1:      No         0         1        0
2:      Yes        0         0        1
3:      Yes        0         0        1
4:      No         0         0        0
5:      No         0         0        1
```

Now I would like to plot a bar chart. The sum of each state column should be one bar (i.e. the sum of state_A should correspond to one bar, the sum of state_B to one bar and the sum of state_C to one bar). Additionally, I would like to group them by the Healthy column, i.e. each bar should be layered. For example, the state_C bar has height 4 (the sum is 4) and it should be made of two colors (one color with height 3 because we have three Healty==Yes and another color with height 1 because we have one Healty==No).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I got you correctly, but I will try.

**Sample data:**

(columns order are not important)

```
   A  B  C Healthy
0  0  1  1     Yes
1  0  1  0      No
2  0  0  1     Yes
3  0  0  1     Yes
4  0  0  0      No
5  0  0  1      No
```

**Graphs:**

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'Healthy': {0: 'Yes', 1: 'No', 2: 'Yes', 3: 'Yes', 4: 'No', 5: 'No'},
        'A': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0},
        'B': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0},
        'C': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1}}

# create data frame from sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# sum by state
df_sum = df.sum(numeric_only=True)

# sum group by state
df_gby = df.groupby(['Healthy']).sum(numeric_only=True)

# plot sum
df_sum.plot.bar()

# plot gby sum
df_gby.transpose().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

**Aggregation results:**

```
# df_sum
A    0
B    2
C    4

# df_gby
         A  B  C
Healthy         
No       0  1  1
Yes      0  1  3
```

**Images/Graphs:**

1. [image: Just a SUM]
2. [image: SUM with GROUP BY]